# NavigationController PushViewController does not show

Tags: swift

I am trying to navigate to the `ClassroomViewController` once I receive the push notification. I have put a break point, and it hits all the lines, but it does not show the `ClassroomViewController`. I am wondering what I am missing in my current implementation.

I added identifier on the `ClassroomViewController` on storyboard.

**AppDelegate**

```
public var keyWindow: UIWindow? {
 return UIApplication.shared.windows.first { $0.isKeyWindow }
}
```

**Helper Method which does not work**. I am wondering why the following approach does not work.

```
private func notificationToNavigate() {
  guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate,
          let topViewController = appDelegate.keyWindow?.rootViewController
  else { return }

  let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
  let cVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"ClassroomViewController") as! ClassroomViewController
  topViewController.navigationController?.pushViewController(cVC, animated: true)
}
```

**Helper Method which works**

```
private func notificationToNavigate() {
  guard let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow else { return }

  let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
  let cVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"ClassroomViewController") as! ClassroomViewController
  window.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: cVC)
  window.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

Comment: Where are you exactly calling this notificationToNavigate() method?

Answer (score 0):

If `topViewController` is indeed the key window's root view controller, then it cannot *have* a navigation controller; if pushing is possible at all, then it must *be* a navigation controller. So you would say

```
(topViewController as? navigationController)?.pushViewController...
```

On the other hand, if `topViewController` is *not* a navigation controller (so that the above fails), then pushing is simply impossible and you need to think of something else to do.

Comment: I have checked while I have been debugging, on the console it shows that topViewController is a UINavigationController, and tried to use the approach that you suggested, it did not work.

Comment: I have updated my question with working one and not working one. I am wondering what i am doing wrong in the not working one.

Comment: Well that doesn't change my answer.